# Enable or disable Amazon S3 bucket replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I have terraform module which is a common bucket module to create all Amazon S3 buckets. The code should be flexible to enable or disable replication on the bucket based on the flag passed.

Would the below code snippet work if I pass var.enable =true for replication enabled bucket and false if replication not required? any links would help to apply this logic.
The same flag is used to enable disable policies resource for the replication bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "source" {
  provider = aws.central
  bucket   = "tf-test-bucket-source-12345"
  acl      = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  replication_configuration {
    role = aws_iam_role.replication.arn

    rules {
      id     = "foobar"
      prefix = "foo"
      status = var.enabled

      destination {
        bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn
        storage_class = "STANDARD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to make `replication_configuration` conditional:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "source" {
  provider = aws.central
  bucket   = "tf-test-bucket-source-12345"
  acl      = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  dynamic "replication_configuration" {

    for_each = var.enable == true ? [1] : []

    content {
      role = aws_iam_role.replication.arn

      rules {
        id     = "foobar"
        prefix = "foo"
        status = var.enabled

        destination {
          bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn
          storage_class = "STANDARD"
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: thnks. this is good to enable or disable replication n the bucket. how to enable or disable the rule on the bucket. the rule itself should be disabled based on environment.  i have \module\s3_bucket and the variable replicatin_configration passed from provisioning module  . can we pass all variables inside rule as null and check replication_configuration==null in modules